# Simulating a pairwise interacting point processes on a 3D surface

Tags: 3d, statistics, simulation, spatial, mesh

I have an irregular 3D mesh representing terrain, and I would like to be able to simulate from a pairwise interacting point processes over that mesh. I can see how this could be done for a homogeneous Poisson point process...

1.Break the mesh into it individual polygons

2.Find the bounding box of each polygon and calculate its area

3.Draw Poisson(lambda*Area) points with uniform random x y coordinates across 
the bounding box and reject those points that fall outside the polygon.

4.Calculate Z coordinate of the points on each plane.

However when it comes to a point process in which points interact (i.e. there is a decreased probability of a point falling within some distance 'r' of another point) things get more difficult. We can simulate these point processes in 2D using rejection sampling, but can anyone suggest an algorithm or approach for simulating this kind of process on an irregular 3D surface?

The best I can come up with is to simulate over the 2D polygon defining the outline of the mesh, which might be approximately correct for a mesh with little variation in the Z axis, but as the variation increased the approximation would be further off and I have no intuition as to the quality of the approximation.

-Thanks

Comment: Which type of point process do you want to simulate? Are you talking about a Gibbs point process with pairwise interaction? Or are you just interested in any model with decreased probability of points close to each other? As I understand you have a 2D surface embedded in 3D, so whenever you have x and y you know z -- is that correct?

Comment: @Ege I'm particularly interested in simulating from a Strauss process, so a point process with interaction radius r and parameters beta and gamma in which each point contributes a factor beta to the probability density of the point pattern, and each pair of points closer than r units apart contributes a factor gamma to the density. Although I am interested in the problem for general cases of pairwise interacting Gibbs processes. You're correct about the  surface, for any x,y we know y.. Something similar to this [mesh](http://www.lionhrtpub.com/orms/orms-10-96/art/graph-2.jpeg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to simulate a Gibbs point process, I think you should modify the spatial birth-death algorithm to fit with your surface/mesh. To use this algorithm you need be able to do two things:

1. Generate a uniformly random point on the surface.
2. Evaluate the Papangelou conditional intensity.

To do 1. I guess you could could cut the surface up in polygons as described in your post and choose a random polygon with probability proportional to its area (the full area -- not the area of the projection onto xy-plane), and then place the point at random inside that polygon.
To do 2. you need to be able to calculate distance on the surface (also between different polygons). If you can do that you should be home safe. Do you follow me?

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense to me. When it comes to evaluating the conditional intensity do you think using the euclidean distance between points on adjacent faces of the mesh would be a good enough approximation?

Comment: Well that is a tough call. If the faces are relatively small and the angles between them not are very acute I guess it would be OK to use the approximation.